# Query to group and count by multiple columns and get a nice representation of the data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model with the `created_at` column and a `state` column (which may have different values, like `A`, nil, etc.), I want to get the amount of records I have in that model, first categorized by `created_at` and then by the `state` column, something like the following...

```
{
  [Wed, 01 Jan 2020]=> { "A" => 662, nil => 1091 },
  [Thu, 02 Jan 2020]=>{ "A" => 2895, nil => 5058 },                                                                                                                                                                                    
  ...
```

The closest I've gotten was this:

```
{
  [Wed, 01 Jan 2020, "A"]=>662,
  [Wed, 01 Jan 2020, nil]=>1091,
  [Thu, 02 Jan 2020, "A"]=>2895,
  [Thu, 02 Jan 2020, nil]=>5058,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  ...
```

With this query: `MyModel.order('DATE(created_at) ASC').group('DATE(created_at)', 'state').count`

How can I get what I want in one query? I'd like it to be as efficient as possible.